# Seeking for pleasure if there is no more love in Marriage

Tags: marriage, sex, love

What should be done if there is no more love in marriage? Can a husband go out and seek pleasure?

Comment: Importance of love as the only factor in marriage dates back to the Victorian era. Although Hindu society acknowledges the importance of love in marital relationship, it doesn't overpower factors like horoscopic conjunctions, caste, economic status,  family honour & sense of duty. To abandon a chaste wife is a grave sin